# Issue installing a bluetooth dongle with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: usb, 20.04, bluetooth

I am trying to use a Bluetooth dongle to connect to a Bluetooth speaker.  I used both the dongle and speaker on a Windows 10 machine to first check it out and worked fine.  I installed the dongle in the Ubuntu machine and see nothing in the Bluetooth device list.
I did some research and tried the lsusb command and the device shows as a
"ID 2687:fb01 Fitbit Inc. Fitbit Base Station"

I'm a absolute novice at Unix with this being my first Linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to get the Fitbit Bluetooth dongle to work is [via Galileo](https://pypi.org/project/galileo/), which is a tool that synchronises a Fitbit with the web service. Galileo can be installed on recent versions of Ubuntu by:

1. remove the Bluetooth dongle from the USB port (if present)
2. add a third-party repository
3. install via `apt` (or `pip`)

This is how you do steps 2 & 3:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cwayne18/fitbit
sudo apt update && sudo apt install galileo
start galileo
```

Alternatively, if you prefer to use `pip`, you can do this:

```
pip install galileo
galileo
```

Once the software is installed, insert the Bluetooth dongle into a USB port and the system should recognise it.

Comment: Thank you.  don't know how i have a Fitbit bluetooth dongle.  I used another generic dongle that is plug and play and it worked right off. Thanks for the research and if this one dies i will need to go back to the old one.